# Can't create instance of 'classname' in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

In the below code

```
<y:base x:Name="baseclass" x:Key="basetest"/>
```

this line prompting error like "Can't create instance of 'base'".

base.vb

```
Imports Tool2DLL
Public Class base
    Inherits WpfBaseToolBar   
End Class
```

In the above code, Tool2DLL is the dll we created and wpfbasetoolbar is the class which in the DLL

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
    xmlns:y1="clr-namespace:Tool2DLL;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1" 
    Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <y:base x:Name="baseclass" x:Key="basetest"/>
     </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How to solve the error. Any idea would be appriciable

Thanks & Regards
jai

Comment: We cannot tell from the little code that you have shown.

Comment: hi Sheridan.thanks for your reply.this is not simple code.i posted the whole code.can u plz check again?